# Parsing PLINK recombination genetic map

Tags: snp, genomics, plink

I have a Plink genetic map with 4 columns: Chromosome, rs-snp, Map(cM), Position(bp) and approximately 8,000 lines find the recombination rate  [Rate(cM/Mb)] from a HapMapII genetic map of 4 columns: Chromosome, Position(bp), Rate(cM/Mb), Map(cM) ~ 47,000 lines ... some chromosomes will be 6 times larger than this; not all Plink entries will be found in HapMapII, but 99% will.

I need to parse PLINK output and spreadsheet VLookUP is too slow.

Basically I have to find one missing field matching two given fields in a much larger file. I have tried variations of grep on Linux and FindStr in windows but they have not worked.

Thank you!

Here is the Plink map

```
Chromosome, rs-snp, Map(cM), Position(bp)
19  rs2312724   0.00187 266034
19  rs1020382   0.002681    267039
19  rs12459906  0.010664    276245
19  rs10409452  0.068867    288246
19  rs3813154   0.092406    292082
19  rs895344    0.099705    292901
... 8300 more rows

Here is the HapMapII map
Chromosome  Position(bp)    Rate(cM/Mb) Map(cM)
chr19   253938  0.154179    0.000000
chr19   256859  0.154528    0.000450
chr19   259772  0.154530    0.000900
chr19   260970  0.154697    0.001086
chr19   261033  0.154888    0.001095
chr19   266034  0.347963    0.001870  <-
chr19   266544  1.256622    0.002047
chr19   266888  1.333840    0.002480
chr19   267039  1.542843    0.002681
chr19   267213  2.171166    0.002950
chr19   267614  1.108918    0.003820
chr19   269380  0.711702    0.005779
chr19   276245  1.791471    0.010664
chr19   277717  2.004476    0.013301
chr19   277776  3.133699    0.013420
chr19   279645  4.135431    0.019277
chr19   280299  4.235347    0.021981
chr19   281360  6.164471    0.026475
chr19   287129  6.113884    0.062038
chr19   288246  6.135026    0.068867
chr19   288320  6.136509    0.069321
chr19   292082  8.817796    0.092406
chr19   292583  9.059132    0.096824
chr19   292901  9.062522    0.099705
.... over 46,000 more lines
```

I need the Rate(cM/Mb) field imported into a version of the Plink map.
Position(bp) 266034 ; and Map(cM) 0.00187 exist in both files; but Rate(cM/Mb) 0.347963 does not. I need to import Rate(cM/Mb) from the larger file into a new version of the smaller file. The columns can be resorted. I don't need the chromosome column. I will add a final column with mutation rate as well.

Comment: What you want to do is a join on two columns, [these answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2619562/joining-multiple-fields-in-text-files-on-unix) show you how to do it. Is that enough for you or I can write a full-length answer later?